# lsmod shows -2 in the “Used by” column

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

This is what happens when i run lsmod on an arm board (banana pi) running on kernel 4.3.0

```
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
async_raid6_recov       1434  -2
async_pq                5548  -2
async_xor               3771  -2
async_memcpy            1665  -2
sha512_generic          8213  -2
rsa_generic             3235  -2
asn1_decoder            2667  -2
mpi                    13730  -2
poly1305_generic        3386  -2
pcbc                    2396  -2
michael_mic             2051  -2
md4                     3536  -2
ghash_generic           1908  -2
gcm                    10511  -2
fcrypt                  8128  -2
echainiv                2110  -2
crypto_user             4316  -2
crc32                   1581  -2
cmac                    2657  -2
chacha20poly1305        6641  -2
chacha20_generic        2902  -2
ccm                     7537  -2
async_tx                1958  -2
asymmetric_keys         3866  -2
arc4                    1882  -2
algif_aead              5293  -2
ablk_helper             1775  -2
cryptd                  7982  -2
dm_crypt               17382  -2
dm_mod                 84208  -2
algif_skcipher          7502  -2
evdev                  10705  -2
nvmem_sunxi_sid         2444  -2
nvmem_core              7792  -2
sg                     23835  -2
sun4i_ts                3948  -2
cpufreq_dt              4349  -2
ohci_platform           4551  -2
ohci_hcd               28715  -2
sun4i_ss               15192  -2
thermal_sys            30747  -2
hwmon                   2571  -2
uio_pdrv_genirq         2949  -2
uio                     7074  -2
#
```

This is /proc/modules just in case it can provide any hint

```
# cat /proc/modules
async_raid6_recov 1434 - - Live 0xbf140000
async_pq 5548 - - Live 0xbf13b000
async_xor 3771 - - Live 0xbf137000
async_memcpy 1665 - - Live 0xbf133000
sha512_generic 8213 - - Live 0xbf12d000
rsa_generic 3235 - - Live 0xbf129000
asn1_decoder 2667 - - Live 0xbf125000 (P)
mpi 13730 - - Live 0xbf11d000
poly1305_generic 3386 - - Live 0xbf119000
pcbc 2396 - - Live 0xbf115000
michael_mic 2051 - - Live 0xbf111000
md4 3536 - - Live 0xbf10d000
ghash_generic 1908 - - Live 0xbf109000
gcm 10511 - - Live 0xbf102000
fcrypt 8128 - - Live 0xbf0fd000
echainiv 2110 - - Live 0xbf0f9000
crypto_user 4316 - - Live 0xbf0f4000
crc32 1581 - - Live 0xbf0f0000
cmac 2657 - - Live 0xbf0ec000
chacha20poly1305 6641 - - Live 0xbf0e7000
chacha20_generic 2902 - - Live 0xbf0e3000
ccm 7537 - - Live 0xbf0de000
async_tx 1958 - - Live 0xbf0da000
asymmetric_keys 3866 - - Live 0xbf0d6000
arc4 1882 - - Live 0xbf0d2000
algif_aead 5293 - - Live 0xbf0cd000
ablk_helper 1775 - - Live 0xbf0c9000
cryptd 7982 - - Live 0xbf0c3000
dm_crypt 17382 - - Live 0xbf0b9000
dm_mod 84208 - - Live 0xbf099000
algif_skcipher 7502 - - Live 0xbf094000
evdev 10705 - - Live 0xbf08d000
nvmem_sunxi_sid 2444 - - Live 0xbf089000
nvmem_core 7792 - - Live 0xbf083000
sg 23835 - - Live 0xbf078000
sun4i_ts 3948 - - Live 0xbf074000
cpufreq_dt 4349 - - Live 0xbf069000
ohci_platform 4551 - - Live 0xbf064000
ohci_hcd 28715 - - Live 0xbf057000
sun4i_ss 15192 - - Live 0xbf04f000
thermal_sys 30747 - - Live 0xbf040000
hwmon 2571 - - Live 0xbf026000
uio_pdrv_genirq 2949 - - Live 0xbf024000
uio 7074 - - Live 0xbf000000
#
```

The thing is I need the 'Used by' field showing the modules, otherwise I wouldn't care, I guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your kernel configuration (`make config`, `make menuconfig` etc.) you need to enable `CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD`:

- When `CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD` is set, the kernel counts references, as you may only unload a module if there are no references to it.
- When `CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD` is not set, then the kernel has no need to count how many references there are to a module, and it always returns `-2` as a marker value.

This answer originally [came from Gentoo Forums](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-951170-view-previous.html?sid=5da509440d09a36e063b6c1d731c4b81).

Answer (score 3):

The module reference count is made available in `/sys/module/<module>/refcnt`, [for modules which can be unloaded](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-module). Modules which are built-in, or on kernels with `CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD`, don’t have a corresponding `refcnt` file.

To determine a module’s reference count, `lsmod` nowadays calls the [`kmod_module_get_refcnt` function](https://sources.debian.org/src/kmod/25-1/libkmod/libkmod-module.c/#L1870) in the `libkmod` library; the latter tries to open the `refcnt` file to read the reference count. For modules which aren’t unloaded, the corresponding file operation fails and sets [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to `ENOENT` (no such file or directory), which is 2 on Linux — and the `kmod_module_get_refcnt` negates that and returns it as the reference count. `lsmod` takes that value and outputs it as the reference count.

This is why `lsmod` shows -2 for modules when `CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD` is not set.