# lsmod 'used by' shows -1 while CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, kernel-parameters

In [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269500/lsmod-shows-2-in-the-used-by-column) there is some explanation about why does `lsmod` show `-2` in *'used by'* column. The idea is that the kernel config option `CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD` was not set.

But what if `lsmod` shows `-1` only for one specific module while `CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD` is set in my current kernel? How to debug this muddle?

Comment: Does `/sys/module/<module>/refcnt` exist for that specific module? If so, what does it contain?

Comment: @StephenKitt It contains `-1` too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A module reference count of -1, visible both in `/sys/module/<module>/refcnt` and in `lsmod`’s output, means that [the module is currently unloading](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.13/source/kernel/module.c#L943).

If a module’s reference count stays at -1, that indicates a problem — `dmesg` should tell you more.